# Using Regular Expressions to Parse Facebook API Long Term Access Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm using the Facebook API Javascript SDK for website login and to various information from the user's profile.  For my server side HTTP request to Facebook for a long term access token I'm using Ruby on Rails with HTTParty Gem.  I'm successfully receiving the token but would like to parse it using RegEx before persisting it to the database.  My response looks as follows:

```
"access_token=long_term_access_token&expires=5183165"
```

I would like to remove the the access_token= from the beginning of the string and the &expires=5183165 from the end of the string.  I would prefer to do this with regex rather than the Ruby gsub method because I would like to preserve the information for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/access_token=(.*?)&/i`:

Here's a working example: http://regex101.com/r/oN6fW0

This ensures that you capture (using parentheses `()`) everything after `access_token=`, and between the next `&` using a non-greedy, 0 or more of *anything* expression `.*?`.